# I am trying to create a function that inputs a name and outputs a rank. what is the best way to create that function?

Tags: python, function

I am trying to create function that takes an input name and outputs a rank based on the order of the letters it has for example `a=1` `b=2`

`name = ab` 
`rank = 3`

```
import string

x = "richard"
y = "donald"
c = "Sam"
numbers = []


for i in range(1,27):
    numbers.append(i)

print(numbers)

alphabet_string = string.ascii_lowercase
alphabet_list = list(alphabet_string)

print(alphabet_list)

new_x = list(x)
new_y = list(y)
new_c = list(c)

zip_iterators = zip(alphabet_list,numbers)
dic = list(zip_iterators)

print(dic)

def rank(name):
    rank = 0
    for l in range(0,len(name)):
        for k,v in dic:
            if l == k:
                v += rank
        print(rank)

rank(new_c)
```

but I failed so far

Comment: so, what's the question?

Comment: how can I create the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
letter_rank = {letter:rank for rank, letter in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase, 1)}

def rank(name):
    return sum(letter_rank.get(c, 0) for c in name.lower())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `ascii_lowercase` constant in the `string` module:

```py
from string import ascii_lowercase

def rank(x):
    total = 0
    for char in x:
        if char in ascii_lowercase:
            total += ascii_lowercase.index(char) + 1
    return total

print(rank('abc'))
```

---

Output: `6`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ord()` built-in function and list comprehension to create the function you need as follows:

```
x = "Villalobos Velasquez Santiago"

def fun(s):
    out = 0
    for i in s.lower():
        if i != " ":
            out += (ord(i)-96)
    return out

print(fun(x))
```

**Output:**

```
333
```

Comment: @the-thonnu Thanks for the suggestion, now I added it into the `for` loop directly and it looks more readable now

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ascii_lowercase.index(letter)` or create a dictionary to lookup the rank of a letter. (My example doesnt't include caps, but you could do so if you wish)

#### lookup with dictionary

```py
from string import ascii_lowercase

alphabet_lookup = {letter:i+1 for i, letter in enumerate(ascii_lowercase)}

def rank(name):
    return sum(alphabet_lookup[c] for c in name.lower())


print(rank('baa')) # outputs 4
```

#### `str.index`

```py
def rank(name):
    return sum(ascii_lowercase.index(c)+1 for c in name.lower())
```